# SQL/Presto: how to get cumulative sum for a startime of items over ds

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a data with the following format. I want to count how many items have been created over time.

```
-- table1
user_id  item_id  start_time  ds
 1         1       1/2/2021   1/1/2021
 1         2       1/1/2021   1/3/2021
 2         5       1/4/2021   1/4/2021
 2         3       1/4/2021   1/4/2021
 2         4       1/5/2021   1/6/2021
```

the desired result is:

```
   cum_count  ds
    1          1/1/2021
    2          1/3/2021
    4          1/4/2021
    5          1/6/2021
```

I think i should get something with window functions but get confused in the partion by and order by part.

What I have for now is

```
select ds, count(start_time) over (partition by user_id order by ds) as cum_count 
from table1
```

but I do not need user level specific cum_count now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want aggregation as well as a cumulative sum:

```
select ds, count(*),
       sum(count(*)) over (order by ds) as running_count
from table1
group by ds
order by ds;
```